# CSS for input placeholder height

Tags: css, input, placeholder

I have a simple embedded form, visible [here](https://aptitude.media). The typeface I am using sits unusually high on the baseline, and as a result the placeholder text (but not the user input) disappears beyond the edges of its container — tall letters like the "l" at the end of "Email" are cut off.

Usually I would adjust something like this by setting the `line-height` appropriately and/or adjusting the `overflow` property but because this is a placeholder nothing seems to affect it.

I can see that the User Agent Style Sheet does this:

```
input::placeholder {
 white-space: pre;
 overflow-wrap: normal;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 line-height: initial;
}
```

I'm not able to override this with new CSS rules (even by using the !important rule). I'm also guessing that's for good reason.

Is there a best practice way of handling this that I'm just unaware of? The input itself as adequate line-height but the placeholder div just doesn't change.

[image: Input properties]

[image: Placeholder properties]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't override the styles with the `!important` keyword either because of an inline style of the property is set or because there is another style marked the same or takes precedence.

don't know about best practices or why this specific font is overflowing but you can set the overflow of the input field to visible & it will work.

in my case I added : `overflow: visible;` in the `input::placeholder` selector

I did it on line 474 in main.css ...

[image]

Comment: Yup, this is it. I had used overflow-y and line-height but maybe not in conjunction. This little combo has fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `overflow-y: hidden;` to `overflow-y: visible;` in your stylesheet, like so:

```css
input::placeholder {
 white-space: pre;
 overflow-wrap: normal;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: visible; /* new style */
 line-height: initial;
}
```

Doing that fixed it in my test.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. Interesting that it fixed it in your test — as per my question, I have this in my stylesheet already but it won't over-ride the User Agent Stylesheet for me. What kind of test did you do?

Comment: Ah, so weird. I inserted into a style sheet via the web inspector in chrome and it worked nicely. Now I can't replicate it. Sorry about that! I did work nicely once, but obviously not a useful solution. :-(

Comment: Very weird. Thanks for digging in. Somehow Gal's answer has found the combination of these elements that does fix it, but it's clearly sensitive.

Comment: Great! Glad a solution was found. :-)